# php multidimensional array keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi guys i have a little trouble with arrays in php. Given an array $all_array and when i var_dump it , php shows me these infos below.

```
   Array ( 
         [0] => Array ( 
             [textQm_id] => 8 
             [textQtxt] => lorem ipsu dolor  title 1 
         ) 
    )

    Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
             [questionQs_id] => 17 
             [questionQm_id] => 8 
             [questionQsuraq] => Lorom ipsum dolor question 1? 
        ) 
    )

    Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
             [questionQs_id] => 18 
             [questionQm_id] => 10 
             [questionQsuraq] => Lorom ipsum dolor question 2? 
        ) 
    )
    .
    .
    .

    Array ( 
         [0] => Array ( 
             [textQm_id] => 9 
             [textQtxt] => lorem ipsu dolor  title 9 
         ) 
    )...
```

How can I get textQtxt values?

Comment: Please provide the code you're using to work with the array and the error that you're getting. It's not possible to help you without these details. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: did you try `value[0]['questionQs_id']`?

Answer (score 0):

```
   Array ( 
             [0] => Array ( 
// try to get the key by index I believe is index 1, then compare key word with the keyword you have of textQtxt then you fetch the value

    if ( [key index] == "textQtxt" )
    
                 {
                   //get the value 
                 }
    
             ) 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Look around function [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), looks like exact solution to your problem. Otherwise try to "flatten" array and then look for the values.